# Android: Install ADT locally

Tags: android, adt

I have already had the  necessary ADT plugins for Android programming in Eclipse.

(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Build id: 20130919-0819)

I know the common way to install them is this [link](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

(to download and install them), but i am curious about installing them when they are exist in my local machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download from Android developer site http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting, 
e.g. [ADT-22.2.1](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.2.1.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Download from android developers site here[link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting)